# How can we genetrate the secret/key to sign in JWT so that it can be used?

Tags: jwt

I want to use the JWT secretorkey in my code.So I need to store it at a different place.How can I generate it?

It is used in the code as follows:

This secret is present in `config/auth`

```
module.exports = {  
  'secret': 'eypZAZy0CY^g9%KreypZAZy0CY^g9%Kr', //how will I generate this??
}
```

In `config/passport.js`

```
var config = require('./auth');
var jwtOptions = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
    secretOrKey: config.secret
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just need a crypto random string you could for example use this
https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm.

In nodejs you can use crypto.randomBytes (https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) to generate cryptographically strong pseudo-random data.

In .Net you can use RngCryptoServiceProvider to generate random sequences

Or if it is one time you could just close your eyes and type a bunch of "random" characters on the keyboard :)